# Ask user to apply columns and rows for a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
//Ask user how many woodchucks to simulate

        while(!validNumber)
        {
            Write("How many woodchucks would you like to simulate? (1 - 100) ");
            int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out woodchuckSim);
            if((woodchuckSim <= 0) || (woodchuckSim > 100))
            {
                WriteLine("\nPlease enter a correct amount of woodchucks to simulate: ");
            }
            if((woodchuckSim >= 1) && (woodchuckSim <= 100))
            {
                validNumber = true;
            }
        }

        //Ask user how many days to simulate

        while(!validDays)
        {
            Write("\nHow many days would you like to simulate? (1 - 10) ");
            int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out numOfDays);
            if((numOfDays <= 0) || (numOfDays > 10))
            {
                WriteLine("Please enter a positive whole number between 1 and 10: ");
            }
            if((numOfDays >= 1) && (numOfDays <= 10))
            {
                validDays = true;
            }
        }

        //Using random class populate each cell between 1 and 50 that represents # of pieces of wood chucked by specific woodchuck on that specific day

        int[,] sim = new int[woodchuckSim, numOfDays];

        WriteLine($"{woodchuckSim} {numOfDays}");
        for (int i = 0; i < sim.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sim.Length; j++)
            {
                sim[i, j] = ran1.Next(1, 50);
                WriteLine(sim[i, j]);
            }
        }

        WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        ReadLine();
```

So this is my code so far, and I keep getting a "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error and I'm basically trying to ask the user to input the numbers of woodchucks and the number of days then populate the 2d array with random numbers. Any help will be really appreciated, and btw I am a beginner in programming. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quercus already said, `Length` property refers to overall size of the array and `array.GetLength(index)` should be used instead.

Moreover, since you are a beginner in programming as you mentioned, I would like to tell you as an advice that it would be better to use `if-else` statement in this case:

```
if((woodchuckSim <= 0) || (woodchuckSim > 100)) {
    WriteLine("\nPlease enter a correct amount of woodchucks to simulate: ");
} else {
    validNumber = true;
}
```

`If-else` statement is pretty basic but important concept in programming and since your `if` hypotheses are mutual exclusive you can use it here for a nicer code.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect cycle bounds. `sim.Length` is an overall size of array, which is `woodchuckSim * numOfDays`.
To get size of each dimension use `sim.GetLength(0)` and `sim.GetLength(1)` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`Length` is the size of the first dimension of the array - the number of Woodchucks in your case. For the size of the other dimensions, you could use `GetLength(index)`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sim.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sim.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        sim[i, j] = ran1.Next(1, 50);
        WriteLine(sim[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This managed to solve it, but it prints out the array in a straight line, do you know what I can do to make it print out in a box-like format and have the number of woodchucks the user picked on the side and the number of days on the top?